# Memcached session manager for session management in EC2 instances

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am new to AWS. Can anyone tell me how can I use memcached session manager with EC2 instances on which tomcat is installed for handling the session data? How can elasticache be used in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a memcached app, here's the basic steps to "Get Started with Amazon ElastiCache":

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Welcome.html

In this context, the Amazon-recommended approach would be to use Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat 7 to deploy your app, then use ElastiCache to scale session management as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your own Tomcats on EC2 instances using the following lib http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/

Elásticache is a memcache and you can configure tomcat to store and retrieve sessions to/from it.